# Why does the Jenkins Git plugin ignore my BRANCH parameter?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins job configuration set up involving Git Source Code Management. The job is parameterized using a Git parameter, as shown below:

[image]

I use this parameter to allow us to start this job manually using a particular branch. I including this parameter in the Branches to build field of the Git section under Source Code Management. There is another Branches to build configured, which is any (`**`). This allows the job to be run automatically after a PR has been merged. You can see this in the screenshot below.

[image]

I am polling GitHub every couple of minutes, and it seems that after a Pull Request is merged, the job eventually runs automatically with the corresponding branch that was just updated. This is only some of the behavior that I want. Unfortunately, this job still uses the branch that was last merged to when I start the job manually using a different BRANCH parameter. (e.g. the job automatically ran the job for branch origin/test2 and when I try to run the job with `BRANCH=origin/master`, that parameter is ignored and the test2 branch is used). Can anyone help me figure out if this is a bug or if there is something wrong with my configuration? Thank you!

Comment: Try remove the ** branch specifier and see whether that works.

Comment: I have removed the ** branch specifier, and unfortunately the job won’t start automatically after a PR merge anymore.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the default value of $BRANCH is correct?

Comment: I believe it is. The other things that I have tried are origin/master, which gives me the same behavior. I have also tried to do ** as the default value and it causes the job to go off automatically every 5 minutes (or for however many minutes set in the cron trigger), which is not exactly what I want. I only want it to be triggered after a PR merge to any branch.

Comment: Did you try master as the default value?

Comment: I just tried it. It appears to be the same behavior. The automatic job start-up seems to be fine, but when I run the job manually using a different branch from the last job run, it uses the same branch as the previous one.

Comment: I just found the same problem. I have mix of jobs, some use only manually run builds and then I use only single Branch Specifier and everything is fine. But mixing a parameter (with `master` as default) and multiple branch specifiers (to trigger the build automatically for multiple branches) messes the parametrized build, so it seems.